# Is there a way to shorten this JS statement for moving elements inside the DOM?

Tags: jquery, performance

I have to move up and across a few divs. I was wondering if there's a faster and more elegant way to get to the correct DOM element, that's equivalent to this:

```
var nextCard = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().prev().prev().find('.soccer');
```

Comment: Sure, you might be able to use `.closest()`; could you share a relevant part of your HTML?

Comment: `$(this).find('>:parent:parent:parent:parent:parent:parent???.soccer')` could be a solution, if there was a CSS selector for previous sibling. It's better to use `id` if your DOM is not repetitive, `class` and `.closest()` if it is. To speed it up you could use `id`s and HTML5 `data-*` attributes to create additional links between your DOM elements. Also, you can add a property to every such element on your page (as it's just a plain JS object) that contains a reference to the element you are searching for, but the property won't persist in case your DOM changes.

Comment: Include your html. There is definately a better way, but we need to see the markup too.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - Thanks, I just assigned them IDs rather than traversing doms. I was thinking maybe there might be a way to move up 6 parent levels with one call in JS, but I think IDs just work here.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever do need to traverse the DOM or using IDS is not possible using the `.parents('selector')` would save a few characters. Also if your DOM count is not huge with many nodes then you could possibly use `.find` straight out from an upper level as it is quite fast for the most part.

Here's an example of using `parents()` instead of `parent().parent().etc`.

http://jsbin.com/pibem/1/edit?html,output

```
<div>    
  <div class="siblings">sibling 1 
    <div class="soccer">Soccer</div>
  </div>
  <div class="siblings">sibling 2</div>
  <div class="siblings">sibling 3
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                8 dom levels in 
                <button type="button" id="ctrl">Test</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $('#ctrl').one('click', function(){

    $(this).parents('.siblings').addClass('red')
    .prev().prev().addClass('green')
    .find('.soccer').text('GOAL!');

    $(this).remove();

  });  
});
</script>
```